# How to install bootstrap ngx in Angular 10 using NPM

Tags: angular, sass, ngx-bootstrap

I have installed ngx bootstrap in Angular 10 Project using following npm command, I am using scss in my Angular

`npm i ngx-bootstrap`

but after install when I used bootstrap codes here it is not working properly. how could I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You will need bootstrap styles:

```
<!--- index.html -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Add needed package to NgModule imports:

```
import { TooltipModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [TooltipModule.forRoot(),...]
  ...
})
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

**Use the Angular CLI ng add command for updating your Angular project.**

- `ng add ngx-bootstrap`

**Or use ng add to add needed component (for example tooltip).**

- `ng add ngx-bootstrap --component tooltip`

**Add component to your page:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
        tooltip="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Simple demo
</button>
```